# Spring Statemachine Forks

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have made good progress with the state machines upto now. My most recent problem arised when I wanted to use a fork, (I'm using UML). The fork didn't work as it is supossed to and I think its because of the persistance. I persist my machine in redis. refer below image.

[image]

This is my top level machine where Manage-commands is a Sub machine Reference And the top region is as it is.

Now say I persisted some state in redis, from the below region, and next an ONLINE event comes, then the machine does not accept the event, clearly because I have asked the machine to  restore the state from redis with a given key. 
bur I want both the regions to be persisted so that either one is selected according to the event. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Below is how I persist n restore

```
private void feedMachine(StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine, String user, GenericMessage<String> event)
        throws Exception {
    stateMachine.sendEvent(event);
    System.out.println("persist machine --- > state :" + stateMachine.getState().toString());
    redisStateMachinePersister.persist(stateMachine, "testprefixSw:" + user);
}

private StateMachine<String, String> resetStateMachineFromStore(StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine,
        String user) throws Exception {

    StateMachine<String, String> machine = redisStateMachinePersister.restore(stateMachine, "testprefixSw:" + user);
    System.out.println("restore machine --- > state :" + machine.getState().toString());
    return machine;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling a bit more how you're doing persistence? i.e. which example code you based on and which classes you're using?

Comment: I have edited my question with code for your refernce

Comment: Hmm, I also see something weird with redis with these deep states. Lemmy poke around bit deeper.

Comment: Ok sure, I will be earger to hear from u

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird as I found some other issues with persistence which I fixed in `1.2.x`. Probably not related to your issues but I would have expected you to see similar errors. Anyway could you check [RedisPersistTests.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/1.2.x/spring-statemachine-build-tests/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/buildtests/RedisPersistTests.java) and see if there's something different what you're doing. I didn't yet try sub-machine refs but I should not make any difference from persistence point of view.

Comment: Hi, is there any way I could pass a parameter to an action using UML

Comment: Could you be a little more specific. What you're trying to accomplish?